# JSon to BI - Reports or Tables

Tags: json, report, business-intelligence

I am having a very complex json with 4 level of hierarchy. i am looking for any tool or options where i can convert that json object to a Table. 
I tried Power BI , any fw other jquery to table options, not able to find a good report.
My ultimate aim is to have them in either excel or a online report  which i can share with my team.

If it is excel, it needs to be multiple rows or if it is an UI  , i need like a clickable option where i can drill down the reports. 
Any pointer will be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your Input guys.. I used Microsoft's Power BI. it is surprisingly Free and takes Data from literally anything.. 
It was very easy and good to use..  Never knew that such a tool existed..

Answer (score 0):

With Talend Data Integration you can parse JSON files into a row-based structure and store the results in an Excel file.

You just need to describe the hierarchy of the JSON file. A lengthly example  for the **tFileInputJSON** component can be found [in the docs](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendComponentsReferenceGuide60EN/tFileInputJSON).

To achieve your goal, you can exchange the **tLogRow** output to a **tFileOutputExcel**.